# Sumifs with vlookup. I think

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need the Wages column on WORKED SHIFTS to equal the sum of the wages by date on the WAGES tab.

It appears I am not able to embed images yet, so I also copied a couple rows below.

So it would look like this:

[image: Example of Spreadsheet]

Worked Shift Tab:

```
Badge Number    Person Number   First Name  Last Name   Full Name   Apply Date Start DTM    End DTM Cost Center Operation   Wages           
420 H540004420  Jeffrey O'Neal  Anderson    Anderson, Jeffrey O'Neal 2/13/2017 2/13/2017 6:00AM 2/13/2017 6:00PM    10221   0   $355.29         
420 H540004420  Jeffrey O'Neal  Anderson    Anderson, Jeffrey O'Neal    2/14/2017   2/14/2017 6:00AM    2/14/2017 6:00PM    10221   0   $355.29
```

Wages Tab:

```
Employee ID Full Name   Effective Date  Wages   Base Wage
H540004420  Anderson, Jeffrey O'Neal    2/13/2017   152.28  25.38
H540004420  Anderson, Jeffrey O'Neal    2/13/2017   203.04  25.38
H540004420  Anderson, Jeffrey O'Neal    2/14/2017   152.28  25.38
H540004420  Anderson, Jeffrey O'Neal    2/14/2017   203.04  25.38
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `=SUMIFS()` to achieve this.

```
=SUMIFS(Wages!$D:$D, Wages!$A:$A, B2, Wages!$C:$C, F2)
```

This will sum column D in `Wages` when both the Person Number and Date match.